# Can a firestore snapshot contain x number of changed documents

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I want to ask about Firestore

Reading [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-v8_4)

When a document is added, removed or modified then I get a signal about that event here in this code from the doc:

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

1. When I start this listener will I then get all document matching  `"state", "==", "CA"` even if it's 100.000 of them? Will they come all at once or in batches?
2. after the above initial all (100.000) will I after that always get one(1) document, like when a doc is modified, added or removed, or can there be like a batch collapsing latency from firestore so I will get 1-to-many in the snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first run the query, you'll get everything that matches that query, with a `change.type === "added"`.  Then you will receive changes as they are made, one by one (unless someone writes a batch at once).

The way to manage this is to add a filter to the collection.  For example, you may want to sort the collection by a date field or a name field.  Then limit the results to a manageable number and [paginate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

```
db.collection("cities")
    .where("state", ">=", "CA")
    .orderBy("state")
    .limit(50)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

Don't forget to add an [unsubscribe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) so that you can remove the listener

Answer (score 1):

You get only the documents that were added/modified/removed however the documentation clearly states the first time when the listener is set up it will return all the matching documents documents.

> The first query snapshot contains added events for all existing
> documents that match the query. This is because you're getting a set
> of changes that bring your query snapshot current with the initial
> state of the query. This allows you, for instance, to directly
> populate your UI from the changes you receive in the first query
> snapshot, without needing to add special logic for handling the
> initial state.

So they do come all along. After that they'll be only the changes i.e. the amount of documents being changed.

> The initial state can come from the server directly, or from a local
> cache. If there is state available in a local cache, the query
> snapshot will be initially populated with the cached data, then
> updated with the server's data when the client has caught up with the
> server's state.

Now with that being said you may be charged for it if the data is coming from the server and not from the local cache.